# How to create a scheduled task in Snowflake that auto-generates new table based on field types?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL query that references existing schemas/tables in snowflake that I can run in worksheets to see my data.

The trouble is I want to make a scheduled task to wrap this SQL query in so that it runs the query every 3hrs and sends the data retrieved by said query to a table that may/may not already exist. If not, I want it to auto-populate the fields of this new table with the right field types.

My resultant data:

```
USER_ID|PATIENT|DATE|QUANTITY|QUANTITY_DURATION|EXPIRATION|MAX_DURATION|LAST_QUANTITY_DAY|DAYS_REMAINING|
1111|2222|2021-01-06 00:00:00.000|1|90|730|90|2021-04-06|-4
...
```

From https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html, I know the syntax generally to be:

```
CREATE TASK mytask
  WAREHOUSE = mywh
  SCHEDULE = '3 HOUR'
AS
INSERT INTO mytable(ts) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

But I'm unsure how to make it more automated such that if someone accidentally deletes the table it will make it again on its own.

Comment: would in your task calling a procedure, that does a CREATE IF NOT EXIST, and then the INSERT INTO work.

Comment: Sure! It doesn’t necessarily have to all be in the same block. Just as long as it serves as a wrapper, collectively, to auto detect the types from fields in any SQL I specify to query my existing tables.